# Ubuntu - Crontab seems to be running my script but not actually doing anything?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, cron

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS Bionic

**sudo crontab -e**

*/5 * * * * /bin/bash -c '/root/checker.sh'

**checker.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! (systemctl is-active varken.service)
then 
/bin/bash -c 'service varken start'
fi
```

**/var/log/syslog**

> Sep 11 09:50:01 Varken CRON[18163]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash -c
> '/root/checker.sh')

> Sep 11 09:50:01 Varken CRON[18161]: (CRON) info
> (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Doesnt seem to actually be doing anything though because when I stop the service and let the cron job run, the service is still not started.

When I run checker.sh myself manually, it starts the service.

I want to run a cron every 5 minutes to start the service if its crashed.

Comment: *No MTA installed, discarding output*. Your script generates an error and cron cannot send the mail with the error.

Comment: Google said that error can be ignored as it isnt fatal. 

Im not trying to mail anything to anybody so I removed postfix. And my entire script is in the post. Nothing there says to mail anything. Just check and start a service.

Comment: varken is a service that sends data to influxdb. AFAIK it doesnt use or  need postfix to send data to influx.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The "No MTA" error _itself_ isn't fatal, of course, but it also implies that the script itself is generating _some other error_ (or some output in general, not necessarily but _possibly_ an error message) that you're not able to see. If you don't have a mailer, then redirect the output (both stdout and stderr) to a file so that you could look at it as part of the investigation.

Comment: It's `cron` which is using email, not `varken`. Install `sendmail` which will enable a local mta and you will be able to view the output in `/var/spool/mail`. I would get rid of the single quotes, you do not need them. You do get output, either it's `active` or `inactive`

Comment: (...Also, as a side note, have you considered using systemd's `Restart=` option to have the service manager itself do the job without needing to use cron?)

Comment: If you don't want to bother with sendmail, add something `>>/tmp/checker.log 2>&1` to the end of the crontab entry to capture output & errors to a file, then look at the log after it runs to see what's going wrong. BTW, is there any reason you're using `/bin/bash -c 'somecommand'` rather than just running `somecommand` directly? Also, why the parentheses around `(systemctl is-active varken.service)`? They just create a useless subshell to run that command.

Comment: Are you sure the script running from cron **can find** `systemctl` or `service` commands? Cron scripts run with `$PATH` largely reduced compared to dekstop session. Use full paths wherever possible.